# How to interrupt child_process by a command given by parent process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, child-process

I am currently working on a project which requires the user to click on an 'execute' button to call a child_process in the backend for executing a time-consuming task. Codes are as follows,

```
let child = child_process.spawn(//args);
let data = '';
let err = '';
for await(const chunk of child.stdout) {
  data += chunk;
}
for await(const chunk of child.stderr) {
  err += chunk;
}
return {"out": data, "err": err};
```

Decoding is omitted here. The task of the child_process would output all results at the end of the process so there would be no output during the task is ongoing.

And the user interface has a button for the user to cancel the task while it is executing. I have tried `if (cancelFlag) {child.kill('SIGTERM')}` right after the `child_process.spawn`, but it would not work. I suppose a **listener** is needed for the child_process?

Great thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

child_process.spawn accepts signal and killSignal in options for aborting process
killSignal is SIGTERM by default, and the solution described in previous answers

But here is an example with **signal** and **abort controller**

```
let abortController = new AbortController();
let child = ChildProcess.spawn("sleep", ["1"], {
  signal: abortController.signal,
});
setTimeout(() => {
  abortController.abort();
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a POSIX system then sending SIGTERM to the child should kill the process by default.

However, on Windows SIGTERM is just available for listening and has no behavior by default https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#signal-events.

If you're programming on Windows you should be able to add a listener for the SIGTERM signal